# What ML Algorithm can "coloquialize" stings of text?

Tags: machine-learning

I am looking to colloquialize short natural language strings and titles to more proper grammar, and do the same in reverse.

For example, I'd like to find an ML algorithm that, given the proper data set and training, can convert "y'all" to "you all" or "she was like" to "she said". Even professional titles: "Director, Human Resources" becomes "Director of Human Resources".

To be clear, I have many thousands of strings that need to be `colloquialized` so I can't do this in a deterministic way.

**Can someone please tell me what the proper ML algorithm would be for this type of thing so that I can research?**

I thought at first that it would be a Naive Bayes classifier until I realized that we would end up with thousands of classification categories and that is no good.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of training set do you have (if any)?  What approaches have you considered?  Have you tried anything yet and what was your experience with what you tried?

Comment: @D.W.--I don't want to give too many details about my dataset here unless it becomes necessary to do so. I have not considered any approaches short of a Naive Bayes Classifier (as mentioned in the post) because I need the community's help in determining where to start (also in the post). Also haven't tried anything, because I am looking for help as to where to start (post). I appreciate your wanting me to come with some effort (I have over 10K rep on SO), but I am looking for answers from people who can simply point me in the right direction. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: It seems that the result should be a list of search/replace pairs. Given training data which is the outcome of such search/replace, it should be easy to find the search/replace pairs. No need to use any machine learning.